# Test errors in loading a css background-image using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, imageurl

My question is, how can I test if a background-image has loaded properly?
Essentially I have some divs,
  `<div id="photo" style="background-image:url('someURL')">` and some get an access denied error, or don't exist, I need to know when so I can avoid having no background image.

I know if they were images I could use `$("#image").error(function(){});` but I, frustratingly can't here, and calling `css.("background-image")` doesn't yield an error, which I thought it might, it just returns the completely useless url. 
My other thought was to use the URL to generate a hidden image element, and test if that loads correctly, but I will be dealing with a lot of images and i'd rather have a more elegant solution.

If anyone knows how I can test that a background image, or image URL, returns an image, I'd be happy.

---

UPDATE
I've tried using an image preloader in the form of;

```
$.each($(".photo"), function(){
  var theURL = $(this).css('background-image'),
    theURL = theURL.replace('url(',''),
    theURL = theURL.replace(')',''),
    testImage = new Image(theURL);
```

But the new test image has no error method, and apparently 0 width regardless of whether it's a problem scr or not, so I'm again stumped. 
I also tried using an [ajax query](http://www.ambitionlab.com/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-using-jquery-2010-01-06), but a peculiarity of this case is that I'm designing a tumblr theme, and the broken links return automatically generated error pages, which ajax seems to think mean the target has loaded.

Comment: there are 100's of posts here regarding image preloaders... works the same if image is for background or image tag

Comment: Hmm, this is news to me, never used image preloaders. Thank you.

Comment: I just looked into this, and I may be wrong, but it seems I would either need a plugin, which would work, but seems a bulky solution to inflict on every page-load for only a few, rare cases; or I will essentially have to make a test div and see if that loads correctly, which is again a heavy load to put on the browser for every image.

Comment: no, definitely don't need plugin or need image placed in a div. Look deeper, `javascript image preloader`

Comment: Ok, so the basic method to create a new Image variable for every div, then test if that can pre-load correctly? My only concern is if that will double the load on the browser per image render?

Comment: first part..image variable for every image you want to retrieve..yes. Not sure what second part means

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21694/discussion-between-olivier-butler-and-charlietfl)